# Unable to deconstruct product type after simplifying in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, algebraic-data-types

I have this simple code in OCaml:

```
type int_pair = int * int;;
type a = A of int_pair;;
let extract (A x) = x;;
```

Testing my `extract` function, it appears to work:

```
# extract (A (1,2));;
- : int_pair = (1, 2)
```

I simplify it, so it only needs one type:

```
type a' = A' of int * int;;
let extract' (A' x) = x;;
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: The constructor A' expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

The funny thing is, I can construct values of `a'`...

```
# A' (1,2);;
- : a' = A' (1, 2)
```

...I just can't deconstruct them. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use

```
type a' = A' of (int * int)
```

This is one of the tricky places in OCaml type specification.

There are two different types involved that are subtly different:

```
type one_field = F1 of (int * int)
type two_fields = F2 of int * int
```

In the type `one_field` there's a single field that's a pair of ints. In the type `two_fields` there are two fields each of which is an int. The tricky thing is that the constructor looks identical:

```
# F1 (3, 5);;
- : one_field = F1 (3, 5)
# F2 (3, 5);;
- : two_fields = F2 (3, 5)
```

These two types are distinct, and are in fact represented differently in memory. (The two-field variant actually takes less space and is slightly faster to access.)